# Auto Generating SQL Scripts based on User Input using Flask, python

Tags: python, sql, flask, auto-generate

**Problem:** There is an *arduous* update script we run for work. It takes a lot of time to update because of security issues. We want to make sure we have edited the update script correctly/want to avoid all permission issues.

**Solution:** Using Flask as a front end gui to eliminate the possibility for adding the wrong value. The Flask app will guarantee correct placement of inputs into the update script by auto generating the script, so we can just copy and paste into SSMS.

---

The current problem I am having is aesthetics. I was able to generate a flask app using user inputs and exports a SQL script. The problem is, the sql looks horrible, here is an example of the output:
[image]

---

Ideally the output would be multi-line, like all current SQL scripts:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET ordercomplete = 1
WHERE UserName = 'testuser' and OrderID = 12345
```

Below are my files:

---

```
#templates  home.html
<!doctype html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>SQL Auto Generate</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-UQiGfs9ICog+LwheBSRCt1o5cbyKIHbwjWscjemyBMT9YCUMZffs6UqUTd0hObXD" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

</head>

<h1>SQL Auto Generate</h1>

<h2>Add the following inputs, select 'Submit' to generate a script for SQL</h2>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <form class="pure-form" method="POST" action="/">
    UserName:<br>
    <input type="text" name="UserName"><br>
    OrderID:<br>
    <input type="number" name="OrderID"><br>
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<br>

<div class="main">
    {% if UserName %}
        <p>
        {% print('''
        UPDATE table_name
          SET ordercomplete = 1
        WHERE
          UserName = {} and OrderID = {}
      '''.format(UserName, OrderID)) %}
        </p>
    {% endif %}
</div>

</body>
```

---

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    UserName = ''
    OrderID = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'UserName' in request.form:
        UserName = request.form.get('UserName')
        OrderID = int(request.form.get('OrderID'))

    return render_template("home.html", UserName=UserName, OrderID = OrderID)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

I also uploaded to github: https://github.com/jpf5046/sqlflask

**Ask:** Is there a better way to create a text output with multi-line via `flask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, HTML ignores extra space, such as line endings. If you want to display the query exactly like you generate it, use [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre):

```
<pre>
    UPDATE table_name
      SET ordercomplete = 1
    WHERE
      UserName = {{UserName}} and OrderID = {{OrderId}}
</pre>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. I haven't seen double `{}` instead of `.format()`, is that a better way to write an app like this?

Comment: It's a part of Jinja2 syntax. In addition to convenience, it filters the content to prevent Cross-Site Scripting attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `br` tags in your html

```
{% if UserName %}
    <p>UPDATE table_name <br>
       SET ordercomplete = 1 <br>
       WHERE <br>
       UserName = {{ UserName }} and OrderID = {{ OrderID }}
    </p>
{% endif %}
```